# Session value changes for multiple user login with same account + Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, session-cookies, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I have website running on VMs under Azure VMSS. Above that, there is public load balancer. Also, have an Application Gateway with Backend Pool of same public Load Balancer IP. And at last in Azure DNS, I have A Record of Azure App Gateway public IP.  The issue is when more than one user logs in with the same user id in respective machines then few session values somehow interchanges with each other that results in the further error of functionality as these session values are stored and then fetched from database. Few points:

1) I tried every possible combination of App Gateway Cookie based Affinity and Load Balancer session persistence but no success.

2) It was previously hosted on AWS and everything was working fine. It had AWS classic load balancer and Barracuda WAF.

Does anyone faced the same issue before? As per this https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4033827/troubleshooting-azure-application-gateway-session-affinity-issues do I have to add FQDN for backend pools as right now every backend pool has IP?

Answer (score 2):

You should not point Application Gateway's backend to a load balancer IP if you want to preserve session affinity. More details below. To resolve the issue you should directly add VMSS as backend pool member of the Application Gateway. You can do this via portal or PowerShell/CLI.

When you point the backend to load balancer IP, the load balancer is doing a 5 tuple (src IP, src port, dest IP, dest port, protocol) hash and sending traffic to an instance in the VMSS based on hash. So in your setup, a user request comes to Application Gateway which does a round robin distribution and then goes to Load Balancer which again does a 5 tuple hash. This is causing the above issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. So you mean to say I dont need any load balancer here?

Comment: Yes, you can add VMSS directly as backend pool member to Application Gateway - without needing a load balancer in between.

Comment: does vmss have internal load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an additional load-balancer behind Application Gateway.
Configure Application Gateway itself, it is a layer-7(HTTP) load balancer, capable of load balancing the web traffic. Refer below url: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-vmss-template

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)